# Optimising the MySQL full text search Query?

Tags: mysql, optimization, full-text-search, query-optimization

I am creating a product search system for a website in php using mysql as database.

Currently we have more than 100K products to search through. I have thought to use MySQL's built in full text feature (Match and Against), instead of Sphinx or Lucene, as our requirements are of low intensity.

So for the time being that we use MySQL's built in full text search feature, could someone help us to optmize this full text search query for better efficiency and less over heads.

As someone has suggested to me on SO that I might not be using Full Text syntax in correct manner.

**CREATE TABLE STRUCTURE**

```
-- Create Table SQL for Product --
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ps_search__p`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ps_search__p` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` text,
  `keywords` text,
  `material` text,
  `material_def_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `s_type` text,
  `s_fabric` text,
  `price` decimal(20,6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `build_type` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `genre` varchar(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'p',
  `categories` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `code` (`code`,`type`,`name`,`keywords`,`material`,`s_type`,`s_fabric`,`categories`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


-- Create SQL Table for S table --
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ps_search__s`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ps_search__s` (
  `id` int(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `s_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `fabric` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(20,6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `genre` varchar(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT 's',
  `categories` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `s_id` (`s_id`,`type`,`fabric`,`name`,`categories`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**FULL TEXT SEARCH QUERY**

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM (
    ( SELECT 
        `id`, `code`, `name`, `material`,`material_def_id`, `s_type`, `s_fabric`, `price`, `genre`, `categories`,
        MATCH (`code`,`type`,`name`,`keywords`,`material`,`s_type`,`s_fabric`,`categories`)
        AGAINST ('+cotton*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS `relevance`
    FROM `ps_search__p`
    WHERE
        ( MATCH (`code`,`type`,`name`,`keywords`,`material`,`s_type`,`s_fabric`,`categories`)
        AGAINST ('+cotton*' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
        AND `s_type` REGEXP '.*'
        AND `s_fabric` REGEXP '.*'
        AND `material` REGEXP '.*'
        AND `price` REGEXP '.*'
        AND `categories` REGEXP '.*'
        )
UNION ALL
    ( SELECT
        `id`, `s_id`, `name`, NULL AS `material`, NULL AS `material_def_id`, `type`, `fabric`, `price`, `genre`, `categories`,
        MATCH (`s_id`,`type`,`fabric`,`name`,`categories`)
        AGAINST ('+cotton*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS `relevance`
    FROM `ps_search__s`
    WHERE
        ( MATCH (`s_id`,`type`,`fabric`,`name`,`categories`)
        AGAINST ('+cotton*' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
        AND `type` REGEXP '.*'
        AND `fabric` REGEXP '.*'
        AND `price` REGEXP '.*'
        AND IFNULL(`categories`, '') REGEXP '.*' )
) AS `tblsearch`
ORDER BY `relevance` DESC
LIMIT 0, 36
```

**AND TO GET QUERY COUNT**

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS() 'recordsnum';
```

Would appreciate even a small help.

Comment: There is no way of getting this query to be any since optimised, use Sphinx, will take less than 2 days and MUCH FASTER!!!

Comment: What purpose do these search criteria serve in your application?  `AND s_type REGEXP '.*'`  They are guaranteed to defeat the use of any index.

Comment: Oh my god, yes, please replace `REGEXP '.*'` with `IS NOT NULL` as soon as you get the chance! Or better, add a `NOT NULL`  constraint on these columns and get rid of this test altogether.

Comment: @Yak, [Ollie] - Some coloumns in my table has data stored in comma separated format e.g., 'Cotton,Linen,Nylon'. Therefor to search for a particular or multiple word in these coloumns I preferred to use `REGEXP 'Cotton|Nylon'` which could not be achieved with `LIKE` operator. And if no keywords are present in search filter I use `REGEXP '.*'` which means match all.

Comment: However will try your suggestion and let you guys know about my success, thanks @OllieJones and [at]YaK for your help, appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all tests `REGEXP '.*'` with `IS NOT NULL`.

Leverage the fulltext indexes, replace tests like `fabric REGEXP 'Cotton|Nylon'` with `MATCH(fabric) AGAINST ("+Cotton" IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR MATCH(fabric) AGAINST ("+Nylon" IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

[Normalize your database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). A column should not contain non-scalar values (such as CSV data). Instead, a one-to-many relationship should be established with a new table.

Comment: Sure had same idea after reading your initial comment, will try that tomorrow, and let you know